# When using nested for loops, how to complete an action if no item in a nested loop triggers an if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a script which iterates over words in a line, checking if the word is in the CMU Dictionary, and if the word is not in the dictionary, adding that word to a list (to count frequency of out of vocabulary words), whilst adding the lines in which all words are in the dictionary to a new file.

I do not know how to do an action (in this case write the line to a file), in the case that everything in a nested loop is successful. In contextual terms, this would be going through each `for word in line.split()` and if no words trigger `if word not in dictionary`, adding the line to a file

At the moment, I am writing all the lines which contain an out of vocabulary word to a new file, however this has two problems:

1) Lines with multiple out of vocabulary words are added multiple times.

2) I need the lines which have no words which are not in the dictionary.

My thought was to use this and then try to later figure out how to iterate over the lines in `RecipeUtterances`, and if the line was in not in `CMURecipeUtterances`, adding it to a new file, however I feel as though there must be a more pythonic way to do it.

```
dictionary = []
for word in nltk.corpus.cmudict.dict():
    dictionary.append(word)


translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)

domain_words = []

with open("RecipeUtterances.txt") as file:
    new_file_2 = open("CMURecipeUtterances.txt", "a+")
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            word = word.lower()
            word = word.translate(translator)  #remove punctuation
            if word not in dictionary:
                print(line)                    #track progress
                new_file_2.write(line + '\n')
                domain_words.append(word)
    new_file_2.close()
file.close()
```

I have included the code I am using, but just to reiterate, I do not intend to have the `new_file_2.write(line + '\n')` to be in the if statement, as I don't want lines which have out of vocabulary words.

Comment: Also hint: using `set` instead of list for `dictionary` can be much faster. Python standard library also has Counters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of indicator when you have written to a file. For instance, you can track whether the number of domain words increased:

```
for line in file:
    domain_words_len = len(domain_words)
    for word in line.split():
        word = word.lower()
        word = word.translate(translator)  #remove punctuation
        if word not in dictionary:
            print(line)                    #track progress
            domain_words.append(word)
    if len(domain_words) > domain_words_len:
        new_file_2.write(line + '\n')
```

or just a boolean variable - this is probably better as it will depend less on the future domain words logic:

```
for line in file:
    new_words_encountered = False
    for word in line.split():
        word = word.lower()
        word = word.translate(translator)  #remove punctuation
        if word not in dictionary:
            print(line)                    #track progress
            domain_words.append(word)
            new_words_encountered = True
    if new_words_encountered:
        new_file_2.write(line + '\n')
```

Also, as pointed above, using `set` for `dictionary` will make your code much faster. Eg:

```
dictionary = {word for word in nltk.corpus.cmudict.dict()}
```

Or even better: [it seems](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/cmudict.html), that `nltk.corpus.cmudict.dict()` is already a dictionary - so it may be possible to do it like:

```
dictionary = nltk.corpus.cmudict.dict()
```

> I need the lines which have no words which are not in the
>   dictionary.

- then you can just add `not` to the condition:

  ```
  if not new_words_encountered:
      new_file_2.write(line + '\n')
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The two examples that you gave outputted lines which included words not in the dictionary once (I'm not sure if you intended this), but the if not new_words_encountered: worked perfectly

Comment: Please see my addition to the answer (about `not`). Does it work now? If not, please prove an example of input and desired output.

Comment: Yes, also thanks for recommending using a set, the current code takes about an hour to run